# Firefox, how to clear url bar for pasting with middle button?

Tags: linux, firefox

I use firefox on Linux. Linux has the excellent  pasting with mouse middle button. Everything you select, you don't need to copy, it's alredy copied and just use the middle button to paste it.

Unfortunately Firefox, as soon you click the URL field, select the URL text, so what you selected previously with mouse is overwritten in clipboard memory. So you can't paste any more URL with middle button in URL bar.

Once upon a time as a workaround with an  extension that was a button that cleared the URL bar, but unfortunately there is no more.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For me pressing `F6` and then backspace works and won't put the selection under my clipboard.

Otherwise holding ctrl+backspace is a much quicker way to clear the address bar without selecting anything.

Comment: The first one work, even if is a bit too complex, I would prefer to not use the keyboard at all. 
The second one doesn't work for me

Comment: Clicking on the bar and holding ctrl+backspace doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately no :-(